# Run a powershell script on machine connected to deployment group in azure

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline with azure. The deployment is working until the final stage where i need to run a powershell/cmd script on the machine that is running the deployment group agent. Can someone please assist on how to run a cmd/powershell script on the machine that is running the deployment group agent?

I have tried using remote powershell but that requires a username and password which i can not use for security reasons.

For context
I have a local server. I have a repo on azure. I have created a pipeline that builds the repo and the artifacts of the build are then copied to my local server. Now I want to run a powershell/cmd on the local server through the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#add-a-powershell-script

> The syntax for including PowerShell Core is slightly different from the syntax for Windows PowerShell.
>
> Push your PowerShell script to your repo.
>
> Add a pwsh or powershell step. The pwsh keyword is a shortcut for the PowerShell task for PowerShell Core. The powershell keyword is another shortcut for the PowerShell task but Windows PowerShell and will only work on a Windows agent.

```yaml
# for PowerShell Core
steps:
- pwsh: ./my-script.ps1

# for Windows PowerShell
steps:
- powershell: .\my-script.ps1
```

However as you would notice, this would only run on the agent.

You can also use the classic alternative, also described in the same documentation using the UI provided by Azure

Another alternative which may be suited for your case is to create a VM extension by navigating to the virtual machine in the Azure Portal, clicking on "Extensions" in the left sidebar, and then clicking the "+Add" button.

Otherwise, your only option may be the "Azure Remote Run", however you mention you cannot get the credentials for that.

Comment: I have tried this but this tries to execute the script on the agent (in azure). I want to execute the script on the machine that the deployment was made.

Comment: Maybe a VM extension is what you're after, I updated my answer, at the bottom